# How to make this stadium roof in Blender?

Tags: modifiers

How to make this roof in Blender using modifiers? This is Bunyodkor stadium. 
[image]
You can search more images on google.

Comment: Hello :). Please, tell us what you tried and where exactly you are stuck. So it's not just asking for a tutorial.

Comment: What have you tried that is not working? What specific part of the process are you having issues with? This site is not for Do-this-for-me kind of questions site or a Tutorials-On-Demand one. Asking for tutorials is considered off-topic. Read: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a tutorial request, not a focused question.

Comment: @cegaton I don't think it would hurt to give a few pointers

Answer (score 2):

Alright...this isn't an answer yet, but I just wanted to include this reference image which helps you get a better sense of the structure for now. This is going to be a long one.

[image]

I'm not going to go into all the fine details on how to go about modelling this, but here are some general tips.

1) Model a single exterior pillar, than use an *Array* modifier then a *Curve* modifier. This will allow you to repeat the pillar across the exterior of the arena.

2) Use a *Cloth* simulation for the drapes. You're going to need to subdivide it a lot, and add a lot of wrinkles into the base cloth mesh so that there is enough cloth to produce the wave effect. The cloth will have to be shaped similar to the arena's curvature, so it doesn't look like a tablecloth draped over the arena.

As for the collision objects, notice in the reference image I included how there appears to be strings pointing towards the center of the arena that are holding up the drapes. Thus, you can imitate this by creating an array of invisible cylinders for the cloth to wrap around.

[image]

3) As far as the physics settings for the cloth go, you're going to want to reduce the various stiffness settings to allow it to bend more easily.

I've done a rough render of the arena shown below using this method. It obviously could use more work, but I think it gets the point across enough.

Hope this helps!

[image]
[image]